# Help! Genymotion won't open back!

Tags: 15.10, 14.10, genymotion

#### Problem:

When i was on Ubuntu 15.10, i installed Genymotion so i can play CoC. I made **really** good friends there, but when i installed Ubuntu Studio, Genymotion wouldn't open! Ubuntu Studio would recognize it as an application, nothing, not even the splash screen wouldn't show. Oh, btw, Ubuntu Studio was installed on the same partition (/dev/sda6) whiich i installed Ubuntu 15.10 on. All the files were copied. So anyways, I **really** ***really*** need Genymotion back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try reinstalling Genymotion and/or Virtualbox.
If you care about your saved CoC state you could backup the Virtual Machine.
Per default they are stored under ~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed.